# Allowing relative font sizes up to a specific maximum

Tags: html, font-size

My website, for the most part, uses relative fonts and fluid layout techniques, so our site layout will scale based on what the browser's default font size is set to. But there are certain elements that have fixed widths, and our layout past a certain font size just doesn't work well or look good. It's not feasible at this point to go back and change all of those elements.

So, I want to allow the site to adjust based on the user's chosen default font size in the browser--within certain limits. For example, things start to look a bit wonky at a browser `fontsize` of `22px;` I'd love to have the site be relative, up until it hits a maximum base size of `22px`.

From what I can gather, there doesn't seem to be any easy way to specify this purely in CSS. I was thinking the best approach is to use `Javascript` to detect the base `fontsize` on page load, and if it's `>22px` then I'll set a style on my body tag to fix `font-size` to `22px`. If it's less than `22px`, I won't do anything (and leave our default relative style in place). I don't care as much about handling font size changes while the page is loaded, as that seems like an edge case (that would get corrected on next page load).

Is this the best approach, or are there better ways?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent users from increasing font size (even if you set the size in pixels, users can just Ctrl +), and many people think this is good – people may need larger font size than you expect, and breaking layout somewhat may be better than not being able to read at all. So what you can do is to make any reasonable effort to ensure that the page works reasonably for a wide range of font sizes.

Comment: I'm not sure you fully understood the question. I know CTRL +/- will zoom the page and increase the font size--that's fine because that's zooming the ENTIRE page (including all of the 'fixed' layout), so everything still renders properly, just zoomed in. And I WANT to allow font size adjustment, up to a certain limit. If I just set my body to a fixed size, say 10px, then no one would be able to change it. I want to keep my font size variable (body: 69%, then em's for children), but make sure that "69% of default" is never > 22px.

Comment: You still cannot. Whether browsers let the user zoom the entire page or just text is not really relevant. And the user can always have `* { font-size: 32pt !important }` in his user style sheet.

Comment: I disagree; it is relevant (in my scenario) whether the browser zooms the WHOLE PAGE vs has a different BASE FONT SIZE. In the former, the layout is preserved and everything fits in the layout. In the latter, it's possible (beyond a certain size) that text no longer fits properly in its container and wraps/overlaps/truncates in less-than-desirable ways. The case I care about is users who have browser font defaults set >22px; I understand someone could override via user style sheets but they do so at their own risk. Given my requirements, shouldn't this be possible?